# Is there a way to load a file using jquery (only javascript maybe?) without using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, file

What I want to know is; Is there a way to load images dynamically (with the only need of putting the img... code) to load a file (the file is in the same server) into a var to parsing it.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to load a .gpl colour palette into a var for doing things with it in a var.

Comment: Then ajax is exactly what you want. It's simple, it's very widely-supported, works well cross-browser, and since you're loading the palette from your own site, there's no Same Origin Policy issue. What's your reason for disallowing ajax?

Comment: the reason is to threat to use that locally if i want without using a server or mount one.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of your question is "and parsing it". You've said in a comment you want to load a .gpl color palette and do things with it in a variable. That's ***exactly*** what ajax is for. It's simple, it's *very* widely-supported, works well cross-browser, and since you're loading the palette from your own site, there's no Same Origin Policy issue. What's your reason for disallowing ajax?

But with that limitation, you're really going to have a hard time. On many browsers, you can load an image into a [`canvas`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) and access its pixels therein, without using Ajax, but you can't currently do that on IE, without using [excanvas.js](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) or similar.

Comment: The image was only an example of what i wanna know. Sorry for my bad explanations , my english isn't so good. I wanna load a normal file with text into a var.

Comment: @Angelus: That's **exactly** what Ajax is for.

Comment: the reason is to threat to use that locally if i want without using a server or mount one. The original idea is to load palettes for seeing their colour in a table.

Comment: @Angelus: Ah, I see. **Really** would have helped to say in the question that you wanted a solution that didn't require a server. I'm afraid you're going to have a hard time doing that. Good luck.

Comment: @Angelus: No worries. The word "threat" isn't what you're looking for, either in *"ok thx anyway for threating to help me with it"* or *"the reason is to threat to use that locally"*. I think you may mean ["try"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/try?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) (that's a link; stoopid StackOverflow not underlining links). ["threat"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/threat?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) is **completely** different.

Comment: thanks for understanding my english xDD , i'll update my memory bank @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden `iframe`. Then you can manipulate it with Javascript.